# Unable to aggregate results in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm an experienced SQL user, but am an absolute MongoDB/JSON newbie.  I'm trying to aggregate results from a couple collections in our database here and keep running into this error: uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :

This is the script I'm using:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
{
    $match:
    {
        $and:
        [
            {
                "updated_at": { $gte: ISODate("2022-01-01") }
            },
            {
                "updated_at": { $lte: ISODate("2022-03-31") }
            },
        ]
    }    
},
{
 $lookup:
     {
        from: 'clients',
        localField: 'client',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'clients'
     }
 },
 {
     $unwind: '$clients'
 },
 {
     $addFields:
     {
         "client_name": "$clients.client_name"
         ,"client_label": "$clients.client_label"
         ,"client_code": "$clients.client_code"
         ,"client_country": "$clients.client_country"
         ,"client_base_currency": "$clients.client_base_currency"
         ,"client_invoice_currency": "$clients.client_invoice_currency"
     }
 },
 {
     $project:
     {
         client_name: 1
         ,client_label: 1
         ,client_code: 1
         ,client_country: 1
         ,client_base_currency: 1
         ,client_invoice_currency: 1         
         ,updated_at: 1
         ,usd_value: 1
     }
 },
 {
      $group:
      {
          _id: 
              { $dateToString: { "date": "$updated_at", "format": "%Y-%m"  } }
              ,"$client_name"
              ,"$client_label"
              ,"$client_code"
              ,"$client_country"
              ,"$client_base_currency"
              ,"$client_invoice_currency"
              ,total_vol: { $sum: "$usd_value" }
      }                 
 }
 ])
```

With some Googling I've been able to put together this script, but now I'm getting stuck.  I'm sure it's happening in the $group stage, as when I comment out that whole part, the query works fine.

I'm basically trying to get the equivalent of this SQL script:

```
select
   (extract(year from t.updated_at) * 100 + extract(month from t.updated_at)) as year_month
   ,c.client_name
   ,c.client_label
   ,c.client_code
   ,c.client_country
   ,c.client_base_currency
   ,c.client_invoice_currency
   ,sum(t.usd_value) as total_vol

   from transactions t

   left join clients c
     on t.client = c._id

   where t.update_at between '2022-01-01' and '2022-03-31'

group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Any suggestions on how to correctly do this?  I know this is fairly basic, but it's not entirely clicking yet, the whole JSON syntax.

Comment: The first stage can be simplified to `{ $match: { updated_at: { $gte: ISODate("2022-01-01"), $lte: ISODate("2022-03-31") } } }`

Comment: The syntax error you're running into is related to how you're expressing the `$group` as you suspect. It's going to be a lot more verbose than `group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7`. Effectively you need to specify the names and values for each field that you are grouping on, and that should all be nested inside of the `_id`. So something like `_id: { date: { $dateToString: { "date": "$updated_at", "format": "%Y-%m"  } }, client_name: "$client_name", ... }` and then you'll have that last `total_vol` line as the only accumulator that is outside of the `_id`

Comment: @user20042973 Thanks, that appears to have solved it.  The query is running and I'm not getting an error.  Though it's not returning results yet, so it's probably a very inefficient query.

Comment: There are some extra stages that aren't needed, but they are probably harmless for performance. How many documents in the `transactions` collection match the `updated_at` filter? Does the `client` field always have a value? Is there an index on `updated_at` (perhaps a compound one that also includes `usd_value`) on the `transactions` collection? I was going to suggest this might be worthy of a new question, and it still might for performance, but realized there is another one about correctness [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186647/mongodb-query-always-returns-0-in-aggregation)